# Angular 2 Custom Theme , SCSS error

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I am new to Angular 2, and brand new to SCSS (I have always used css). I am trying to setup a custom theme for my angular-cli project that goes along with our branding colors.

I found a stackoverflow question ([Angular2 Material - Real custom theming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440998/angular2-material-real-custom-theming)) that I thought would work, but sadly I am getting a error that looks like a problem with Angular 2 parsing my .scss custom theme file. I have made the necessary addition of my .scss file in the angular-cli.json located in the root of the application, and placed the new .scss file in the src folder alongside the style.css originally created by angular-cli project setup. Below is the .scss file I created.

```
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/all-theme';

@include md-core();

$ae-brand-indigo: (
    50: #e0ebf3,
    100: #b3cee1,
    200: #80adce,
    300: #4d8cba,
    400: #2673ab,
    500: #005a9c,
    600: #005294,
    700: #00488a,
    800: #003f80,
    A200: #6a9bff,
    A400: #3778ff,
    A700: #1e67ff,
    contrast: (
        50: $black-87-opacity,
        100: $black-87-opacity,
        200: $black-87-opacity,
        300: $black-87-opacity,
        500: white,
        600: white,
        700: white,
        800: white,
        900: white,
        A100: $black-87-opacity,
        A200: $black-87-opacity,
        A400: $black-87-opacity,
        A700: white,
    )
 );

$ae-brand-orange: (
    50: #fef3e4,
    100: #fde0bb,
    200: #fccc8e,
    300: #fab861,
    400: #f9a83f,
    500: #f8991d,
    600: #f7911a,
    700: #f68615,
    800: #f57c11,
    900: #f36b0a,
    A100: #ffffff,
    A200: #fff1e9,
    A400: #ffd1b6,
    A700: #ffc19c,
    contrast: (
        50: $black-87-opacity,
        100: $black-87-opacity,
        200: $black-87-opacity,
        300: $black-87-opacity,
        400: $black-87-opacity,
        500: white,
        600: white,
        700: white,
        800: white,
        900: white,
        A100: $black-87-opacity,
        A200: $black-87-opacity,
        A400: $black-87-opacity,
        A700: white,
   )
 );

// mandatory stuff for theming
$ae-primary: md-palette(ae-brand-indigo);
$ae-accent:  md-palette($ae-brand-orange);
$ae-warn: md-palette($md-red);

// include the custom theme components into a theme object
$ae-main-theme: md-light-theme($ae-primary, $ae-accent, $ae-warn);

// include the custom theme object into the angular material theme
@include angular-material-theme($ae-main-theme);
```

I get the following error stacktrace when building and starting up my dev server.

> ERROR in
>   ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/ae-main-
>   theme.scss Module build failed: undefined
>           ^   Argument `$map` of `map-get($map, $key)` must be a map
>
> Backtrace:
>       node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/_theming.scss:19, in
>       function `map-get`
>       node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/_theming.scss:19, in 
>       function `md-palette`
>       stdin:76
>       in C:\Users\jstafford\Desktop\working\ae-
>       ui\node_modules\@angular\material\core\theming_theming.scss (line 19, 
>       column 14)
>       @ ./src/ae-main-theme.scss 4:14-166
>       @ multi styles
>
> ERROR in ./src/ae-main-theme.scss)` must be a map

Now, I know I am defining a custom palette here. The only examples I have seen on the material 2 getting started page use $md-red, $md-indigo and the different hues of that color that are predefined. Can anyone help me to get this working so I can truly customize like I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440998/angular2-material-real-custom-theming).  **What am I missing?**

Comment: being new to scss, I left the import 'variables' out because I thought it was something that was unique to the scss setup of the person who originally posed this in the stackoverflow question I referenced. Not sure if this is related to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I forgot a `$` sign on my indigo variable (this is what caused the parser exception):

```
$ae-primary-palette: md-palette($ae-brand-indigo);
/* -----------------------------^ */
```

I also added my choice of primary and secondary colors:

```
$primary-color: map-get($ae-primary-palette, 500);
$secondary-color: map-get($ae-accent-palette, 500);
```