# Angular Material Custom Theme with Custom Palette

Tags: css, node.js, angular, sass, angular-material

I'd like to apply the palette:

[Palette](https://material.io/resources/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=0&primary.color=46828D&primary.text.color=f4f2f3&secondary.color=276c8a&secondary.text.color=ffffff)

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ADAMJR/pen/JjYbQYR)

Here is my current theme file:

```
@import "~@angular/material/_theming";

@include mat-core();

$app-primary: mat-palette(#46828d);
$app-accent: mat-palette(#276c8a);
$app-warn: mat-palette(yellow);

$app-theme: mat-dark-theme($app-primary, $app-accent, $app-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($app-theme);
```

Not sure how to use SASS lol

Project: https://github.com/theADAMJR/2PG-Dashboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I eventually created a custom theme, using custom palettes (Angular 9)

[Generate Colour Palette](http://mcg.mbitson.com/)

```
@import "~@angular/material/theming";

@include mat-core();

// generated custom palette
$primary-palette: (
    50 : #e9f0f1,
    100 : #c7d9dd,
    200 : #a2c0c6,
    300 : #7da7af,
    400 : #61949d,
    500 : #45818c,
    600 : #3e7984,
    700 : #366e79,
    800 : #2e646f,
    900 : #1f515c,
    A100 : #9cecff,
    A200 : #69e3ff,
    A400 : #36d9ff,
    A700 : #1dd4ff,
    contrast: (
        50 : #000000,
        100 : #000000,
        200 : #000000,
        300 : #000000,
        400 : #000000,
        500 : #ffffff,
        600 : #ffffff,
        700 : #ffffff,
        800 : #ffffff,
        900 : #ffffff,
        A100 : #000000,
        A200 : #000000,
        A400 : #000000,
        A700 : #000000,
    )
);

$primary: mat-palette($primary-palette);
$secondary: mat-palette($mat-blue);
$warn: mat-palette($mat-yellow);

$theme: mat-dark-theme($primary, $secondary, $warn);

// apply the dark theme
@include angular-material-theme($theme);
```

[How can I use custom theme palettes in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440998/how-can-i-use-custom-theme-palettes-in-angular)

Answer (score 1):

try like this.

```
// Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
$cdx-app-theme: mat-light-theme($cdx-palette-primary, $cdx-palette-accent, $cdx-palette-warn);

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include angular-material-theme($cdx-app-theme);

// Create aliases to use within your app (Do not override the `$cdx-palette-*` properties)
$my-app-palette-primary: mat-palette(#46828d);
$my-app-palette-accent: mat-palette(#276c8a);
$my-app-palette-warn: mat-palette(yellow);
```

let me know if you have doubt.

Comment: `SassError: Undefined variable.`
`  ╷`
`6 │ $cdx-app-theme: mat-dark-theme($cdx-palette-primary, $cdx-palette-accent, $cdx-palette-warn);`
`  │                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^`
  ` |`

Using Angular `9.2.0`

Comment: U will have to define $cdx-palette-primary, accent, warn