# how to create a theme with a custom color in angular?

Tags: angular, themes, mdc

All the examples I've come across use a pre-existing palette, like $indigo-palette. For example here:

```
https://material.angular.io/guide/theming
```

I don't want to use any indigo, pink or any pre-defined palette. I want to create a theme with my custom specific color, for example '#bbbbbb'. How can I do that?

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41446746/735398