# Angular Material 16 Custom Theme implementation?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm upgrading an application and I was using a site that generated a custom Angular Material Theme .css file (https://materialtheme.arcsine.de)

However, that does not include all of the components that Material offers.

I'm looking the MATERIAL DESIGN PALETTE GENERATOR (http://mcg.mbitson.com/) - But I have no idea on how to implement the output of what it generated?

I found this answer: [How can I use custom theme palettes in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440998/how-can-i-use-custom-theme-palettes-in-angular) - but is there anyway to do this just a .css file?  I don't really want to use .scss.

Another question I have is, does this work in conjunction with the styles already in place with my various .css files?

```
$mdThemingProvider.definePalette('tcweb', {
  '50': 'e0eaf1',
  '100': 'b3cbdb',
  '200': '80a9c4',
  '300': '4d86ac',
  '400': '266c9a',
  '500': '005288',
  '600': '004b80',
  '700': '004175',
  '800': '00386b',
  '900': '002858',
  'A100': '8ab4ff',
  'A200': '5793ff',
  'A400': '2473ff',
  'A700': '0a63ff',
  'contrastDefaultColor': 'light',
  'contrastDarkColors': [
    '50',
    '100',
    '200',
    'A100',
    'A200'
  ],
  'contrastLightColors': [
    '300',
    '400',
    '500',
    '600',
    '700',
    '800',
    '900',
    'A400',
    'A700'
  ]
});
```